# Will our Beta label be removed?

Tags: discussion, graduation, beta

Since we learned that [Matter Modeling is graduating](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/298/5) and [Quantum Computing is graduating](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/517/2293) and [Freelancing is graduating](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/340/25010), I'm curious if AI will be too?

Comment: Is there any general post regarding this instead of meta posts on individual sites?

Comment: Apparently a post will be made on Meta.SE in December, but for now we're all just curious about which sites will be graduating!

Answer (score 2):

Indeed it will; we have just posted [an announcement](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2828/1641) (as a separate post, seemed more sensible for visibility).